# Convert $ to Numeric

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R in the following format. 'Sum' is a factor varaible, want to convert that to numeric so that calculations can be done. How do I convert the 'Sum' variable to numeric?

```
Sum
250
3000.2846874029
$1,000,000
-$400,030
$700,000
```

Comment: Please conform to the correct standard of displaying data on stackoverflow. This will help to clarify your problem as well as possible solutions as it is currently unclear what structure your data might be in

Comment: What are the typical values of Sum?  If they are all digits, then you can convert it to numeric by `as.numeric(as.character(Sum))`.  Otherwise, please provide, for example, the outcome of `unique(Sum)`.  In addition, is "Quantity ppp yyy bbb" relevant?

Comment: Quantity is not relevant here. Just ignore. I edited the dataset above, captured all the variations.

Comment: From the link `destring(df$Sum, "-0-9.")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in the correct format as shown below:

```
  Quantity  Sum
1      ppp  $45
2      yyy -$23
3      bbb   35
```

The process to clean your data would look as follows. First, when you read in the data, set `read.csv("data.csv",stringsAsFactors=F)` then use `gsub` and `as.numeric` to convert the column:

```
df<-read.csv("data.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)

df$Sum<-as.numeric(gsub("\\$|,","",df$Sum))
```

Comment: R is giving this error - Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion